# SublimeLinter "max-line-length" setting not applied

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I'm having difficulty setting user settings for SublimeLinter in SublimeText3. I've checked here: http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/settings.html

I've tried setting my user settings, and setting "max-line-length" to 80 (the default is 100):

```
{
    "user": {
        "debug": false,
        "delay": 0.25,
        "error_color": "D02000",
        "gutter_theme": "Packages/SublimeLinter/gutter-themes/Default/Default.gutter-theme",
        "gutter_theme_excludes": [],
        "lint_mode": "background",
        "linters": {
            "pylint": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "disable": "",
                "enable": "",
                "excludes": [],
                "max-line-length": 80,
                "paths": [],
                "rcfile": "",
                "show-codes": false
            }
        },
        "mark_style": "outline",
        "no_column_highlights_line": true,
        "passive_warnings": false,
        "paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "python_paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "rc_search_limit": 3,
        "shell_timeout": 10,
        "show_errors_on_save": false,
        "show_marks_in_minimap": true,
        "syntax_map": {
            "html (django)": "html",
            "html (rails)": "html",
            "html 5": "html",
            "php": "html",
            "python django": "python"
        },
        "warning_color": "DDB700",
        "wrap_find": true
    }
}
```

However, this setting is not applied. I have closed and re-opened sublime text. How do I get this setting to be applied? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax you are using seems to work for some *linters*, however, as far as I know it doesn't works for *pylint*.

Anyway, for using *pylint* from *Sublime Text* **you can use the command argument *--max-line-length=N***,
so change

```
"args": []
```

for

```
"args": ["--max-line-length=90"]
```

In addition, if you do this, remove the *max-line-length* property.

---

**Edit**: where to place SublimeLinter settings.

You can learn about it in the [SublimeLinter settings documentation](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html)

I used the user-settings-file, that you can usually find using the following menu option: *Preferences > Package Settings > SublimeLinter > Settings-User*. For this purpose you need to add the option inside *linters/pylint*:

```
{
    "user": {
        "linters": {
            "pylint": {
                // "exampleOtion": "exampleValue",
                "args": ["--max-line-length=90"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that probably your config file is similar to the one in the question, so you just need to add the new option inside *"pylint"* without breaking the JSON format

Comment: Voted down as the answer does not say where to put the config option, also, adding the config option doesn't do anything.

Comment: @JeffDavenport I've updated my answer to add that info. And I've just tested this and it works. If you have any problem with this, feel free to let me know it so I can help you.

Comment: Thanks, upvoted, however it appears that this option is only applicable for pylint and does not seem to have any affect in the SublimeLinter-haml-lint package

Comment: If you're adding this to your `users` file, you need to remove the `"users": {` definition. Copying and pasting the above doesn't work. This does: ```{
    "linters": {
        "pylint": {
            "args": ["--max-line-length=125"]
        }
    }
}```

Answer (score 0):

*As this message continues to appear regularly on the first page of Google and SublimeLinter has changed a lot, here is my solution:*

I enter "pref lint" or "preferences linter" in the [Command Palette](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/command_palette.html) in sublime text 3 ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO2Ud.png)) to open the preferences file.

Here's the `SublimeLinter.sublime-settings` default config file I am using ([W0312](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:w0312) is for using tabs instead of spaces):

```
// SublimeLinter Settings - User
{
    "linters": {
        "pylint": {
            "filter_errors": ["warning:", "W0312"]
        }
    }
}
```

I use [pylint-messages](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com) to find the right error/warning codes, with the help of the [search box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV8ry.png).